# Postgres 13 join from another table on JSONB array of String

Tags: postgresql, join, jsonb

I have a table with JSONB column. In this column we store identifiers of another table as json array of strings. How can I join the tables

Table Customer:

| CustomerID | Name | Campaigns (JSONB) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | [ "rxuatoak", "vsnxcvdsl", "jkiasokd" ] |
| 2 | Mick | [ "jdywmsks", "nxbsvwios", "jkiasokd" ] |

Table Campaign:

| CampaignID | Identifier | CampaignName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | rxuatoak | Alpha |
| 2 | vsnxcvdsl | Bravo |
| 3 | jkiasokd | Charlie |
| 4 | jdywmsks | Delta |
| 5 | nxbsvwios | Echo |

Result something like:

| CustomerID | Name | CampaignNames |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Alpha, Bravo, Charlie |
| 2 | Mick | Delta, Echo, Charlie |

I tried many ways, and could only find online help with json objects inside the jsonb column. My jsonb column has simple array of strings.

Using POSTGRES 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a `JOIN` operation between the two tables on condition that an identifier is found within a campaign (using `?` operator). Then apply aggregation with `STRING_AGG`, with respect to the "*CustomerID*" and "*Name*"

```
SELECT customer.CustomerID,     
       customer.Name_,
       STRING_AGG(campaign.CampaignName, ',') AS CampaignNames
FROM       customer
INNER JOIN campaign
        ON customer.Campaigns ? campaign.Identifier
GROUP BY customer.CustomerID,   
         customer.Name_
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gb8A45rnfSVC6USDEUcj5n/0).